# Popular tabela com dados tabela HTML

Tags: php, mysql, table

Eu tenho uma tabela com 4 colunas (nome, prova1, prova2, simulado).
Suponha que você seja um professor, e que deseja postar as notas dos alunos. Eu retorno para você o seguinte:

```
// $l representará o número de linhas que existem
$l = -1;

// $inst2 carrega: SELECT nome, prova1, prova2, simulado FROM alunos

while($dado = mysqli_fetch_row($inst2)) {

      $l+=1;
      $dados[] = $dado;

}
for ($x=0; $x<=$l; $x++) {
 echo "<tr>";
 for ($y=0; $y<=3; $y++) { 
       if ($y==0) {
       echo "<td>".$dados[$x][$y]."</td>";
       } else {       
       echo "<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$dados[$x][$y]."\" size=\"6\"></td>";
       }
 }
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>
```

Ou seja, as cédulas da tabela em que não existem valores registrados ainda (são nulos), terão em seu conteúdo um `input` para o professor inserir a nota do aluno.

O meu problema é: Eu quero que tenha um botão para que depois que o professor inserir as notas ele clique nele e estas sejam salvas no banco de dados.

Eu até pensei em fazer assim: colocar a tabela que aparece na tela dentro de um form, e colocar nos `inputs text` um nome usando as variáveis `$x` e `$y`. E adicionar uma coluna com um id para cada linha (`auto_increment`). Contudo, não consegui seguir em frente. Mesmo porque acredito que exista uma maneira melhor para isso.

PS: Eu **prefiro** sua ajuda usando procedural.
Obrigado!

Comment: Quer fazer isso com ajax ou carregar a página de novo?

Comment: Eu quero que quando o professor submeta os dados mostre para ele a tabela nova. Ou seja, com os novos valores inseridos por ele.

Comment: Ok, e quer fazer isso com ajax ou carregar a página de novo?

Comment: Carregue novamente.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <?php
    require("header.php");

    //iniciar a pesquisa no banco de Dados para povoar a tabela
    //criar a conexão com o banco de dados
    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'escola');

    if (!$link) {
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    //Selecionar todos os registros da tabela
    $query = "SELECT * FROM alunos" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));
    $result = $link->query($query);
    $cont=0;
    ?>
    <body>

        <form method="POST" action="gravarNotas.php">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>prova1</th>
                        <th>prova2</th>
                        <th>simulado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <!-- iniciando loop para povoar a tabela --> 
<?php
//Criando variável para armazenar os dados
//Adiciona o ID para poder fazer a gravação no banco posteriormente
$tabela = "Notas";
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['idalunos'];
        //Saber quantos resgistros existem na tabela
        $cont++;
        
        $tabela .= " <tr>"
                . "<td><input type='text' name='nome_$id' id= '{nome_$id}' value='{$row['nome']}' ></td>
                   <td><input type='text' name='nota1_$id' value='{$row['nota1']}' id= '{nota1_$id}'></td>
                   <td><input type='text' name='nota2_$id' value='{$row['nota2']}' id= '{nota2_$id}'></td>
                   <td><input type='text' name='simulado_$id' value='{$row['simulado']}' id= '{simulado_$id}' ></td> "
                . "</tr>";
    }
    
}

echo $tabela;
?>




                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- passando para o post a qtd de registros -->
            <input type="hidden" name="totalRegistros" value="<?=$cont;?>">
            <button type="submit">Enviar notas</button>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Aqui você gerou o html e inseriu os resgistros na tabela. Quando clicar em "Enviar notas", será executada a ação do "action". Assim a página a ser carregada será a gravarNotas.php. Essa página irá realizar a gravação no banco.

```html
<?php
  $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'escola');

    if (!$link) {
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
     
    if($_POST && $_POST['totalRegistros'] > 0){
         for($i=1; $i<=$_POST['totalRegistros']; $i++ ){
             
             #apenas para ficar mais compreensível
             $nome = $_POST['nome_'.$i];
             $nota1 = $_POST['nota1_'.$i];
             $nota2 = $_POST['nota2_'.$i];
             $simulado = $_POST['simulado_'.$i];
             
             #executa a gravação no bando de dados
              $query = "UPDATE `escola`.`alunos` SET `nome`=' {$nome}', `nota1`= '{$nota1}', 
                  `nota2`= '{$nota2}', `simulado`= '{$simulado}' WHERE `idalunos`='{$i}'";
;             $result = $link->query($query);
         }
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: Tem como me explicar o que é aquilo que você colocou como value?

Comment: vamos lá: <?=@$nome;?> aqui eu indico que essa parte do código é php, pois o restante eh html. O @ é para impedir que o php lance exceção caso a variável. O que  esteja vazia. e o restante é a pŕopria variável. Se vc quiser, pode inserir toda a lógica de pesquisar no banco e alimentar a variável, antes do html.

Comment: Uma dica, Israel, é legal -ainda que brevemente- explicar porquê seu código resolve o problema apresentado. Isso ajuda o leitor atual e futuro a ler/entender o código/solução. . . . Ou mais diretamente, a explicação no seu comentário devia ser uma edição na resposta.

Comment: Esse seu código só tá pegando os dados do banco e botando na tabela. Isso aí eu já fiz. Ta lá no código. O que eu quero é  exatamente a parte que você não fez. Salvar o que o usuário inserir nos inputs em um banco de dados... E outra a tabela terá inúmeras linhas, exigindo o uso de loops.

Comment: Refatorei o código e coloquei os comentários.